# discord.js message.author.id returns undefined in dms but works in a server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

okay so i made this bot with a verify system but the
`let memberTarget = client.guilds.cache.get('811543610897989683').members.cache.get(message.author.id);`
part has a problem in it the `message.author.id` part doesnt seem to work in dms with the bot it only works after i ran the command once in my server and then when i resart the bot it doesnt work anymore in dms, is there anyway how i can make this work?

the rest of my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const ignSchema = require('../schemas/ign-schema')
const mongo = require('../mongo')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client


module.exports = {
    commands: ['verifyme'],
    minArgs: 0,
    maxArgs: null,
    expectedArgs: "<minecraft name>",
    callback: async (message, arguments, text,  client, e) => {
      
      
        const playerName = arguments.join(' ')
        

        

        fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=MY_API_KEY&name=${playerName}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async data => {
          


            player = data
            const target = message.author
            const author2 = message.author.tag
            const uuid = data["player"]["uuid"]
           const discordid = data["player"]["socialMedia"]["links"]["DISCORD"]
           
           
           const guildSetup = '712363102737530931'
          const guildSetup2 = '811543610897989683'
          
         

            let verifyRole = client.guilds.cache.get('811543610897989683').roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '[Verified]');
           
            let memberTarget = client.guilds.cache.get('811543610897989683').members.cache.get(message.author.id);

            const guildId = '811543610897989683'
            const userId = message.author.id
            const UUID = uuid
            const _id = UUID
            const author = message.author
         
            
           

           if(discordid == author2) {
            
            await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
              try {
                const results2 = await ignSchema.findOne({
                  _id,
                  
                })
                const { UUID, userData, discordName } = results2
                
               message.reply(`dd ${memberTarget}`)
                if (UUID == uuid) {
                  if (author2 == discordName) {
                    

                    if (memberTarget.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "[Verified]")) {
                      message.reply('you are already verified')
                      memberTarget.roles.add(verifyRole)
                    } else {
                    memberTarget.roles.add(verifyRole)
                    message.reply('welcome back')
                    }
                  } else {


                    message.reply(`you already used this minecraft account to verify ${discordName}, if you want to change this please contact <@390929478790152192>`)
                    mongoose.connection.close()
                    return
                  }
                
        
                
                } else {

                }
              } catch {
                console.log(e)

                

                const userData = {
                  
                 
                  timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                  
                }
                await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
                  try {
                    await ignSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                      _id
                    },
                    {
                      
                      UUID,
                      discordName: author2,
                      HypixelName: playerName,
                      userId: userId,
                      guildId: guildId,


                      $push: {
                        userData: userData
                      },
                     
                      
                    }, {
                      upsert: true
                    })

                    memberTarget.roles.add(verifyRole)
                    message.reply('you are succesfully verified')

                  } finally {
                    mongoose.connection.close()
                    
               
                  }
                })
              }
            })
            } else {
            message.reply(`change your linked discord account in hypixel from ${discordid} to ${author2},`)
    
           }
           console.log(`${discordid}`)
           
           
           
        })
        
        
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("Network error", error)
          message.reply(`error: could not find a player named: ${playerName} check if you ever joined hypixel or try again later`)
          return
        })
        

    },
 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a dm channel:

```js
if(message.channel.type === "dm") {
   // you can do anything you want here. In my case I put console.log() function.
   // since you wanted user ID, you can use message.author.id property here.
   console.log(`Recieved DM from ${message.author.tag}, DM content is`, message.content);
}
```

surely you dont need to fetch a user, since theres 1 user in the dm. Simply use:

```js
let user = message.author;
```

Comment: the `client.guilds.cache.get` is bascally  getting the guild of the id i gave it so i can give some one a role in my server after they verifeid themself in the dms and thanks for your reply i will try it out now

Comment: I know what the code does, but how are expecting guild specific code to work in a dm?

Comment: what do you mean with guild specific code

Comment: how do you think `client.guilds.cache.get` works? you cant use this code in a dm, because a dm is **not** a guild.

Comment: someone told me i had to use that in order to give someone a role in a specific guild from dms

Comment: ahhh, apologies, that is correct. I see what you're trying to do now - please let me know if you get any errors from the above code

Comment: ohhhw no problem

Comment: if my code worked, please mark it as correct

Comment: in your message event listener

Comment: it still returns memberTarget as undifined

Comment: are you certain the guildID is valid? I can't see why it wouldnt work, the code is correct if youre using my method

Comment: yeh and the wierd thing is if i do the command once in my server and then in the dms then it actually works but i have no clue why it doesnt normally

Comment: that sounds exactly like a cache error, try fetching the id first

Comment: and how do i do that

Comment: like how do you fetch the id

Comment: just figured it out it works now after fetching the user id